# Updating SQL Server DateTime columns in VB.NET

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

When updating records some `DateTime` values may look like `2015-06-25T01:35:52Z` or `13 jun 2014`

So when writing query I do:

```
Dim Query As String = "Update Activities set ActivityDate = '" & theDate & "' where customerid = 10"
```

(using vb.net)

but results in error. Is there a `DateTime` conversion I can use?

Comment: Try changing the format in the application.  The first format should be accepted by SQL Server.

Comment: I get an error using the first format as well.

Comment: Remove the `Z` off the end.  The documentation is clear that ISO 8601 is supported for input (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).

Comment: You mention an error twice _what is the error message?_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.Parameters.Add`:

MSDN: [SqlCommand.Parameters Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

A parameterized query can handle this datetime conversion for you:

```
Protected Sub UpdateCustomerActivityDate(customerID As Integer, activityDate As DateTime)
    Dim sql As String = "Update Activities set ActivityDate = @activityDate where customerid = @customerID"
    Dim cmd As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@customerID ", Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = customerID
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@activityDate ", Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = activityDate
    Try
        Using connection As New SqlConnection(YourConnectionString)
            connection.Open()
            cmd.Connection = connection
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Sub
```